# Using ne...ni...ni with rien and personne

Tags: grammaire, négation, ordre-des-mots, infinitif, double-négation

I want to say the following sentences in French. Please see if my attempts are correct!

I am not going to eat or drink anything.

*Je ne vais rien ni manger ni boire.*

or

*Je ne vais rien manger ni boire.*

Similarly, which of the following sentences is correct?

*Je ne peux ni effrayer ni blesser personne*

or

*Je ne peux effrayer ni blesser personne*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I**

"Not […] or […] anything" has the following renderings.

- **ni…ni…quoi que ce soit**, ** ne rien […] et ne rien […]**, **rien […] ou […]

The first sentence is slightly wrong; here are  correct forms.

- Je ne vais **ni** manger **ni** boire **quoi que ce soit**.
- Je ne vais rien manger et ne rien boire.
- Je ne vais rien manger ou boire.

The second second form, is  correct: "*Je ne vais rien manger ni boire.*". A comma could be used after "manger" (in general after the first verb).

(1905) [ne rien faire ni dire (1)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=t5TRUXAiUSEC&q=%22rien+faire+ni+dire%22&dq=%22rien+faire+ni+dire%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg54-t-u_rAhVJLBoKHRgwDAgQ6AEwLHoECEsQAg)
(1958)                                [(2)](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&id=_jwTAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22rien+faire+ni+dire%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22rien+faire+ni+dire%22)
(2010)                                [(3)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Qf9IOuOGAAsC&pg=PT27&dq=%22rien+faire+ni+dire%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg54-t-u_rAhVJLBoKHRgwDAgQ6AEwIHoECDMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22rien%20faire%20ni%20dire%22&f=false)
(1905) [ne rien faire, ni dire](https://books.google.fr/books?id=YY5PAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22rien+faire+ni+dire%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22rien+faire+ni+dire%22)

**II**

"*Je ne peux ni effrayer ni blesser personne*" est correct, c'est l'usage standard.

"*Je ne peux  effrayer ni blesser personne*" est aussi correct, mais c'est l'usage littéraire, lequel est précisé dans [**I. A. 2. du TLFi**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ni).

> Littér. [Ni est omis devant le premier terme coordonné] Ne ... a ni b.
> c) [Coordonne des verbes]
> – Le soleil ne se lève ni ne se couche (Crèvecoeur, Voyage, t.2, 1801, p.118).
> – Je n'ai demandé ni souhaité d'être député (Courier,Pamphlets pol., Au réd. Drapeau blanc, 1822, p.196).
> – Dans l'auberge de l'Isola Bella, les auditeurs n'ont entendu ni su que ce que le narrateur a bien voulu leur confier (Gobineau,Pléiades, 1874, p.29).
> – Nancy ne répond, ni ne bouge (Camus, Requiem,1956, 1repart., 1ertabl., p.824).

Answer (score 2):

1. The first one would just be:

> *Je ne vais ni manger ni boire.*

*Rien* is redundant but if you want to emphasize the fact you'll eat/dring nothing:

> *Je ne vais ni manger ni boire quoi que ce soit.*

Using both *rien* and *ni* would make an heavy double negation, i.e. a positive statement:

> *Je ne vais ni rien manger, ni rien boire.* -> Despite what was expected, I will both eat and drink.

---

2. The first sentence is correct:

> Je ne peux ni effrayer ni blesser personne.

You might also sligthly modify the second one that (literary) way:

> Je ne peux effrayer ou blesser personne.